# iOS How to merge two NSArrays and remove Duplicates based on Unique ID in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In My Project I want to Merge two arrays and Remove the duplicates based on Unique ID and add the missing objects from second array as a child array of the merged array in swift?

Here I give the First NSArray:

```
[{
    AccountNumber = 134679852;
    AssessmentRollId = 12;
    AssessmentYear = 1995;
    City = houston;
    DateCreated = "2018-01-22T18:43:53.6";
    DateModified = "2018-01-22T18:43:53.603";
    FIPS = 40125;
    Id = 1223;
    LandUseCode = 40125;
    LotSizeSquareFeet = 45;
    PropertyId = 3177;
},
    {
    AccountNumber = 134679852;
    AssessmentRollId = 12;
    AssessmentYear = 1995;
    City = houston;
    DateCreated = "2018-01-22T18:47:23.94";
    DateModified = "2018-01-22T18:47:23.943";
    FIPS = 40125;
    Id = 1224;
    LandUseCode = 40125;
    LotSizeSquareFeet = 45;
    PropertyId = 3177;
}]
```

This is the second Array:

```
[{
    AccountNumber = 547427;
    City = "Berlin";
    FIPS = 48453;
    InspectionId = 143;
    InspectionLogId = 90;
    InspectionType = "Property Owner";
    InspectionTypeId = 1;
    ScheduledDate = "2018-01-22T00:00:00";
    TemplateId = 1110;
    TemplateName = "Beta validation Jennish";
    UserId = 3177;
    UserPropertyId = 1225;
},
    {
    AccountNumber = R157509;
    City = "Santa Fe";
    FIPS = 48167;
    InspectionId = 144;
    InspectionLogId = 91;
    InspectionType = "Property Owner";
    InspectionTypeId = 1;
    ScheduledDate = "2018-01-22T00:00:00";
    TemplateId = 1111;
    TemplateName = "beta validation 3";
    UserId = 3177;
    UserPropertyId = 1226;
}]
```

Please Help me for find the solution, I am little bit weak in Technical Knowledge Because now only I am learning..

I want to make this type parent child format:

```
[{
    AccountNumber = 134679852;
    AssessmentRollId = 12;
    AssessmentYear = 1995;
    City = houston;
    DateCreated = "2018-01-22T18:43:53.6";
    DateModified = "2018-01-22T18:43:53.603";
    FIPS = 40125;
    Id = 1223;
    LandUseCode = 40125;
    LotSizeSquareFeet = 45;
    PropertyId = 3177;
    InspectionDetails:{
            InspectionId = 143;
            InspectionLogId = 90;
            InspectionType = "Property Owner";
            InspectionTypeId = 1;
            ScheduledDate = "2018-01-22T00:00:00";
            TemplateId = 1110;
            TemplateName = "Beta validation Jennish";
            UserId = 3177;
            UserPropertyId = 1225;
    }
}]
```

This is I tried to Remove Duplicates Using Set..

```
let mergedArray:NSArray = Array1.addingObjects(from: Array2 as! [Any]) as NSArray
            let mySet = NSSet(array : mergedArray as! [Any])
            let uniquArray:NSArray = mySet.allObjects as NSArray
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you facing problems?

Comment: how about using NSSet ?

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: I tried but unable to add parent datas,let mergedArray:NSArray = self.propertyArray.addingObjects(from: openOrderArray as! [Any]) as NSArray
                let mySet = NSSet(array : mergedArray as! [Any])
                let uniquArray:NSArray = mySet.allObjects as NSArray
This is I am tried..@CRDave

Comment: I Updated the question..@Anbu.karthik

Comment: I using set to remove duplicates@iOSGeek

Comment: First off, this is Swift. Try to use `Array` instead of `NSArray`. They work mostly the same but `Array` is easier to work with in many circumstances. Same goes for `Set` and `NSSet`. Second, what is the "unique ID" you are talking about? I don't see it as a key in any of the arrays.

Comment: The key Unique ID name is "Id"@ColGraff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I hope you have an array of dictionaries (String:Any), and it is really merging of dictionaries with in the arrays is that you want, correct me if I am wrong . If you havent had the requirement of having child data, this would have been easy. You could have created an extension for dictionary and looped through each dictionary item in the array and merge those, since that is not the case, I came up with an idea with which I achieved what you want, below is the code (not much error handling, not much performance test done and I modified your test data and made Accountnumber as unique Id and made an edit in the second array data so that the unique id exists between the arrays)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var firstArray:[[String: Any]]!
    var secondArray:[[String: Any]]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        prepareData()
        mergeDictionaries()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func prepareData(){
        let acc1:[String: Any] =     ["AccountNumber" :134679852,
                                      "AssessmentRollId":12,
                                      "AssessmentYear" :1995,
                                      "City":"houston",
                                      "DateCreated":"2018-01-22T18:43:53.6",
                                      "DateModified":"2018-01-22T18:43:53.603",
                                      "FIPS" :40125,
                                      "Id":1223,
                                      "LandUseCode":40125,
                                      "LotSizeSquareFeet" :45,
                                      "PropertyId" :3177]
        let acc2:[String: Any] =     ["AccountNumber" :134679854,
                                      "AssessmentRollId":12,
                                      "AssessmentYear" :1995,
                                      "City":"houston",
                                      "DateCreated":"2018-01-22T18:43:53.6",
                                      "DateModified":"2018-01-22T18:43:53.603",
                                      "FIPS" :40125,
                                      "Id":1223,
                                      "LandUseCode":40125,
                                      "LotSizeSquareFeet" :45,
                                      "PropertyId" :3177]

        firstArray = [acc1, acc2]

        /// Fill the second array
        let acc3:[String: Any] =     [    "AccountNumber" :134679852,
                                          "City" :"Berlin",
                                          "FIPS" :48453,
                                          "InspectionId" :143,
                                          "InspectionLogId" :90,
                                          "InspectionType" :"Property Owner",
                                          "InspectionTypeId" :1,
                                          "ScheduledDate" :"2018-01-22T00:00:00",
                                          "TemplateId" :1110,
                                          "TemplateName" :"Beta validation Jennish",
                                          "UserId":3177,
                                          "UserPropertyId" :1225]

        let acc4:[String: Any] =     ["AccountNumber" :547427,
                                      "City" :"Berlin",
                                      "FIPS" :48453,
                                      "InspectionId" :144,
                                      "InspectionLogId" :91,
                                      "InspectionType" :"Property Owner",
                                      "InspectionTypeId" :1,
                                      "ScheduledDate" :"2018-01-22T00:00:00",
                                      "TemplateId" :1111,
                                      "TemplateName" :"Beta validation Jennish",
                                      "UserId":3178,
                                      "UserPropertyId" :1226]
        secondArray = [acc3, acc4]
    }
    // This method will loop through each dictionary data in the first array and find the corresponding dictionary in the second array and then find the difference of data as a new dictionary and then create a final merged disctionary with the new data as a new key, then this dictionary will be added to a new array which finally contains all the merged data
    func mergeDictionaries(){
        var mergedArray = [[String: Any]]()
        for dict in firstArray{

            var mergedDict = dict
            let accNumber = mergedDict["AccountNumber"] as! Int

            // Find the data from second array which is related to the one in the first array, assuming AccountNumber is unique
            let filtered = secondArray.filter{ $0["AccountNumber"] as! Int == accNumber  }

            if filtered.count == 0{
                continue
            }
            // Get the new data from the second dictionary
            let missingData = mergedDict.diffData(dictionary: filtered[0])
            print(missingData)
            // Add the new data as a new dictionary to the merged dictionary
            mergedDict.updateValue(missingData, forKey: "InspectionDetails")
            print("Merged data is \(mergedDict)")
            mergedArray.append(mergedDict)
        }
    }
}


extension Dictionary {
    func diffData(
        dictionary: Dictionary<Key, Value>)->[Key: Value] {
        var dict = [Key: Value]()
        for (key, value) in dictionary {
            // Key already exists dont do anything, we want only new keys fro the second dictionary.
            if ((self[key]) != nil){
                continue
            }
            dict[key] = value
        }
        return dict
    }
    /// function to do simple merge of two dictionaries
    mutating func merge(
        dictionary: Dictionary<Key, Value>) {
        for (key, value) in dictionary {
            self[key] = value
        }
    }

}
```

The merged dictionary will contain the below data and I believe this is what you wanted, this dict is then added to a new merged array

```
["AccountNumber": 134679852, 
"Id": 1223, 
"InspectionDetails": ["InspectionType": "Property Owner", 
                 "TemplateName": "Beta validation Jennish", 
                 "UserId": 3177, 
                 "TemplateId": 1110, 
                 "InspectionId": 143, 
                 "InspectionTypeId": 1, 
                 "ScheduledDate": "2018-01-22T00:00:00", 
                 "InspectionLogId": 90, 
                 "UserPropertyId": 1225], 
"City": "houston", 
"AssessmentRollId": 12, 
"LotSizeSquareFeet": 45, 
"FIPS": 40125, 
"DateModified": "2018-01-22T18:43:53.603", 
"LandUseCode": 40125, 
"DateCreated": "2018-01-22T18:43:53.6", 
"PropertyId": 3177, 
"AssessmentYear": 1995]
```

Comment: Partially this is correct, I will try with your code and make it want I want.. Thanks Bro..

Comment: Here I have some another problem, First of all I want make the InspectionDetails as a child format(Missing Objects in firstArray) of secondArray like result then only want to check the unique ID is same or not, If same means remove the duplicates from secondArray and add the InspectionDetails to firstArray else not same means I want to add the SecondArray(After formatted) with InspectionDetails to firstArray.

Comment: Your answer only helpful for me, please help me to implement the final thing.

Comment: @B.SaravanaKumar As I understood, you want the data in the secondarray to have the inspectiondetails as child format before merge right? As per my experience it should be the job of backend, who ever gives the second array should give the data like that, you should not do that activity at the client side. Discuss with the backend folks to give the data like that

Comment: Bro I know already I asked, that should be the job of backend but they are not ready to do that.